# How to integrate Kotlin inline class with Android data binding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

Kotlin introduced [inline class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html) which is strong typed type alias. This can be useful when use with database. For example,

```
inline class Age(val value: Int)
inline class Height(val value: Int)
```

When they are written to database, they are compiled to `Int` but Kotlin can prevent you accidentally putting a `Height` into a `Age` Field. If you use type alias or `Int` directly, it is possible with type alias but inline class produces a compile time error.

However, these also cause problems with Android data binding. I get `data binding error` when I try to bind a `String` inline class to a `String` attribute.

While it is possible to write some kinds of adapter to bypass this, but it defeat the purpose of using inline class and not practical for creating adapters for all inline classes.

I would like to ask are there any elegant ways to solve this issue?

Comment: What if you take your **inline class** as variable in layout as **data binding**, is it still the problem?

Comment: @JeelVankhede This does not work. If I have `inline class Name(val value : String)` and bind `MutableLiveData<Name>()` to a `EditText.text`, it throws compilation error. But I am  able to bind  `MutableLiveData<String>()`. Even you bind the inline class directly, it still fail.

Comment: What about wrapping inside `ObservableFields`? It's new feature to Kotlin itself,so i think it might take time to get adapted to Android environment.

Comment: @JeelVankhede It is the same that it should work with `MutableLiveData` if you overload`setValue(String)`, `postValue(String)` and `getValue(String)` but is there a way that can be written once and for all, i.e. write only once for all  String inline class.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is inline classes are not just wrappers around primitive types. They are more than type Aliases.

Now coming to your example, even though `DataBinding` has the understanding that if you put any `MutableLiveData<T>` instance in `xml`, it will take that value of that particular variable(something like `mutableLiveData.value`). But if you put `MutablLiveData<Age>`, `mutableLiveData.value` will always be of Type `Age` but not type `Int`.

Note that `inline class`, creates a completely new type and not just a type alias.

I believe that you somehow need a method in your data binding, that returns the value contained in the inline class object.